# Prevent scaling an item when scaling the view rect

Tags: c++, qt, transformation, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I am using Qt's `QGraphicsView` — and `QGraphicsItem` — subclasses.

Is there a way to not scale the graphical representation of the item in the view when the view rectangle is changed, e.g., when zooming in. The default behavior is that my items scale in relation to my view rectangle.

I would like to visualize 2d points which should be represented by a thin rectangle which should not scale when zooming in the view. See a typical 3d modelling software for reference, where vertex points are always shown at the same size.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Set the `QGraphicItem`'s flag `QGraphicsItem::ItemIgnoresTransformations` to true does not work for you?

Comment: This indeed ensures the size of the item is correct, but at least in my case the positions are off after the transform. For example, when I draw a polygon in my app, and add child rectangle items in an unscaled (1:1) view, I get the following result: http://grafit.mchtr.pw.edu.pl/~szczedar/nozoom.png . After scaling and with the flag set, it looks like this: http://grafit.mchtr.pw.edu.pl/~szczedar/zoomout.png

Comment: The docs say the item with the flag set stays anchored to the parent, but I created the rect object with the the polygon as the parent and it didn't work. Tried the underlying pixmap item as a parent as well, no change.

Answer (score 10):

Extend a QGraphicsItem class, override `paint()`.

Inside the `paint()`, reset the transformation's scaling factor to 1 (which are `m11` and `m22`), and save the `m11` (x scaling factor) and `m22` (y scaling factor) before the reset.

Then, draw like you would normally do, but multiply your x with `m11` and y with `m22`. This avoids drawing with the default transformation, but explicitly calculates the positions according to the scene's transformation.

```cpp
void MyItem::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *item, QWidget *widget)
{
    QTransform t = painter->transform();
    qreal m11 = t.m11(), m22 = t.m22();
    painter->save(); // save painter state
    painter->setTransform(QTransform(1, t.m12(), t.m13(),
                                     t.m21(), 1, t.m23(), t.m31(),
                                     t.m32(), t.m33()));
    int x = 0, y = 0; // item's coordinates
    painter->drawText(x*m11, y*m22, "Text"); // the text itself will not be scaled, but when the scene is transformed, this text will still anchor correctly
    painter->restore(); // restore painter state
}
```

The following code block is drawing with default transformation:

```cpp
void MyItem::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *item, QWidget *widget)
{
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    painter->drawText(x, y, "Text"); 
}
```

You can try both to see the difference.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QtGui/QGraphicsScene>
#include <QtGui/QGraphicsView>
#include <QtGui/QGraphicsRectItem>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QGraphicsScene scene;
    scene.addText("Hello, world!");
    QRect rect(50, 50, 100, 100);
    QGraphicsRectItem* recti = scene.addRect(rect);
    QGraphicsView view(&scene);

    // Set scale for the view
    view.scale(10.0, 5.0);

    // Set the inverse transformation for the item
    recti->setTransform(view.transform().inverted());

    view.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

As you can see the text is scaled up but the rectangle is not. Note that this does not only prevent the scaling for the rectangle but and other transformation.

Answer (score 2):

The following solution worked perfectly for me:

```cpp
void MyDerivedQGraphicsItem::paint(QPainter *painter, const StyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{
    double scaleValue = scale()/painter->transform().m11();
    painter->save();
    painter->scale(scaleValue, scaleValue);
    painter->drawText(...);
    painter->restore();
    ...
}
```

We can also multiply the `scaleValue` by other measures, we want to keep its size constant outside the save/restore environment.

```cpp
QPointF ref(500, 500);
QPointF vector = scaleValue * QPointF(100, 100);
painter->drawLine(ref+vector, ref-vector);
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that if I derive a new class and reimplement the paint function, I can do:

```cpp
void MyDerivedQGraphicsItem::paint(QPainter *painter, 
                                   const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, 
                                   QWidget *widget)
{
  double scaleValue = scale();
  double scaleX = painter->transform().m11();
  setScale(scaleValue / scaleX);
  QGraphicsSvgItem::paint(painter,option,widget);
}
```

Comment: setScale scedules a redraw of the item so I guess that your code can lead to an infinite loop. And painter->transform().m11() gives the scale if and only if no rotation is applied to the item.