# How to draw a real point using QGraphicsItem

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsitem

I now have a TXT file with 100,000 two-dimensional (x, y) points.

I want to display it in a QGraphicsView, so I customized a QGraphicsItem, and the paint function draws a point.

But I found that when I zoomed in, this actually drew a rectangle:

```cpp
void CustomPointItem::paint(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem* option, QWidget* widget)
{
    QPen pen{};
    pen.setColor({ 255,0,0 });
    pen.setWidth(1);
    painter->setPen(pen);
    painter->drawPoint(0, 0);
}

QRectF CustomPointItem::boundingRect() const
{
    return QRectF{ -1,1,2,2};
}
```

[image: point drawn as a small rectangle]

Is this how it should be? Or I did something wrong with the code?

I want to know how to better display very large number of points in Qt.

Comment: It's an old thing that "drawPoint" actually draws a very short line using all active states for painter. The size of your item becomes larges when zooming in, so that exceeds size of a pixel

Comment: @Swift - Friday Pie so what is the right way to draw a point(i mean a round point like a dot)

Comment: You should inherit your CustomPointItem class from QGraphicsEllipseItem.

Comment: but the point x,y pos in my txt file are very close (for example p1 :-2.90074 -0.194869
p2:-2.90074 -0.144869), use ellipseItem to draw,points will overlap

Comment: I want an effect similar to a 2D point cloud

Comment: Your item shold somehow ignore scale if you zoom, so it always would be a pixel-sized rectangle. I never had done that QGraphicsScene, that feels like a wrong tool for the task for amount of calculations (unless there are different constraints which require exactly this tool)

Comment: Might be a doube: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222914/qgraphicsview-and-qgraphicsitem-don%C2%B4t-scale-item-when-scaling-the-view-rect

Comment: thx it really helps me@Swift - Friday Pie i